# How to connect k750 logitech keyboard without USB?

Tags: macos, keyboard, bluetooth

I have a k750 keyboard that I would like to connect to a computer via Bluetooth. I know normally you'd just plug the dongle in but is it possible to forgo that and connect using my laptops bluetooth? Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The K750 is not a Bluetooth keyboard. It connects to a "Logitech Unifying" receiver using a proprietary protocol, that is converted into a USB HID class by the receiver.

So unless your laptop doesn't have a "unifying" receiver built-in (as opposed to bluetooth) you must use a Logitech receiver.

Comment: Gotcha, I've found this project https://github.com/xenogenesi/hidclient. I'm a little shaky on the detials but in theory If i plug the USB into a raspi and then forward the signal over bluetooth somewhere else that might work..